# Parallel rectangles covering circle problem

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, recreational-mathematics

Problem:
Given a circle that is just barely covered by a parallel collection of adjacent rectangular boards that have length at least as much as the diameter of the circle, prove that the circle cannot be covered by the same boards if they are arranged in a non parallel configuration.

This is problem 11c from the chapter 19 appendix (integration) of Spivak's calculus 4th ed. I've thought of a few ideas, but I am not sure how to proceed with them and make progress.

I was considering looking at an extreme scenario, with an arbitrarily high number of rectangles which are very long. If I can prove this scenario fails, then any other one must too, since one large piece is just multiple smaller pieces and increasing the length of a piece cannot decrease coverage.

I was also considering looking at total area each rectangle covers minus the overlapped area with another rectangle. I was thinking about working with an expression for the total covered area, and somehow showing that only a parallel arrangement can make the total equal to the circle's area.

I am stuck at the moment and any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: This is not meant to be an ordinary coursework problem. Maybe the tag "recreational-mathematics" should be added.

Comment: What do you mean by "barely covered"?

Comment: @SergioEnriqueYarzaAcuña I'm guessing based on the figure that "barely covered" means that the sum of the widths of the rectangles is equal to the diameter of the circle. Including or excluding the endpoints shouldn't matter to the problem.

Comment: I came across this problem, as well. The solution manual's argument is not particularly satisfying...at least, I cannot understand the logic. I do get the hunch, though, that this is sort of a 'quasi-conservation of mass' kind of problem...in the sense that, for every instance of overlap *within* the circle, there must be some corresponding (though perhaps not equal in magnitude) non-covered territory that also arises *within* the circle.

Comment: In a non-purely parallel configuration, there is necessarily one rectangle that has at least one immediate neighbor that it is non-parallel with (i.e. it has an overlap with this immediate neighbor). In order to cover the corresponding naked spot that arises from this overlap, we must have other rectangles rotated appropriately...but this necessarily forces these other rectangles to cross over (i.e. overlap) the original referenced rectangle and/or its immediate neighbor.

Comment: Of course, then, these overlaps create new naked spots...etc, etc. Consequently, any time we attempt to cover a naked spot, we always create a new one. However, if we have no overlap to begin with, then we have no naked spots...and the 'no overlap to begin with' condition is simply when all the rectangles are parallel.

Unfortunately, I haven't the slightest idea of how to formalize this argument to test its validity.